# Qt + Tesseract как исправить проблемы

Tags: c++, qt

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно прописать в про файле путь к либам.

```
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>

int main()
{
char *outText;

tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
// Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
    exit(1);
}

// Open input image with leptonica library
Pix *image = pixRead("/usr/src/tesseract/testing/phototest.tif");
api->SetImage(image);
// Get OCR result
outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);

// Destroy used object and release memory
api->End();
delete [] outText;
pixDestroy(&image);

return 0;
}
```

Проблемы :

:-1: ошибка: cannot find -lGL

:-1: ошибка: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `LIBS += Lpatch -lfile`
`path` - путь к каталогу с либой.
`file` - имя файла *.lib, *.a или *.dll

Answer (score 0):

решил проблему , ниже срр и pro файлы

cpp`

```
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string outText;

tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();

if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
}

// Open input image with leptonica library
Pix *image = pixRead("/home/tomko/Downloads/tesseract/testing/eurotext.tif");
api->SetImage(image);

// Get OCR result
outText = api->GetUTF8Text();

std::cout << outText << "\n\n";

return 0;
}
```

pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++14
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/tesseract \
           /usr/local/include/leptonica \
           /usr/local/include/

LIBS += /usr/local/lib/libtesseract.so.4.0.0 \
    /usr/local/lib/liblept.so.5.0.1
```

но при создании виджета все равно была проблема - cannot find -lGL 
ее решил методом установки libgl - `sudo apt-get intall libgl-dev`